# How to make a bootable USB in Catalina

Tags: bootable-disk, catalina

```
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     149.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 79.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                527.0 MB   disk1s3
```

> $ mkdir /tmp/recv
>
> $ sudo mount -t apfs /dev/disk1s3 /tmp/recv/
>
> $ ll BaseSystem.dmg

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  496664671 Jun 18 15:09 BaseSystem.dmg
```

> $ hdiutil mount BaseSystem.dmg

```
Checksumming Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)…
Protective Master Boot Record (MBR :: verified CRC32 $D80226F2
Checksumming GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1)…
 GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1): verified CRC32 $3488C747
Checksumming GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Table : 2)…
GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Tabl: verified CRC32 $FB2C82B9
Checksumming  (Apple_Free : 3)…
                    (Apple_Free : 3): verified CRC32 $00000000
Checksumming disk image (Apple_HFS : 4)…
.............................................................................................................................................
          disk image (Apple_HFS : 4): verified CRC32 $E3D25767
Checksumming  (Apple_Free : 5)…
......................................................................................................................................................
                    (Apple_Free : 5): verified CRC32 $00000000
Checksumming GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 6)…
GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table: verified CRC32 $FB2C82B9
Checksumming GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 7)…
  GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 7): verified CRC32 $B193AD93
verified CRC32 $C286C93C
/dev/disk2              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk2s1            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/macOS Base System
```

> $ cd /Volumes/macOS\ Base\ System/
>
> $ cd Install\ macOS\ Catalina\ Beta.app/Contents/Resources/
>
> $ sudo ./createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/test/

```
/Volumes/macOS Base System/Install macOS Catalina Beta.app does not appear to be a valid OS installer application.
```

Do I have to download full pack again, even when I just want BaseSystem to boot up?

Comment: Use the same _format_ of the `createinstallmedia` _command_ for **macOS Mojave** while substituting the appropriate **application bundle name**.  Have a look at: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

Comment: This is the same as other OS. If you have a different question just edit the title to explain how your request is different other than which version you have today.

Comment: @bmike as you can see, I used the "guided" method, but it prompted me "does not appear to be a valid OS installer application" and when I try to download od Mojave, the System Update denied me from accessing that version.